# Intent is undefined

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I get that my `Intent` is undefined, something to do with the constructor of this class, but I'm too new at Java to figure out the problem, maybe you can help?

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, myPlayService.class);
```

the code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    podcastPlayerLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_podcast_player, container, false);


    try {
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, myPlayService.class);

        // --- set up seekbar intent for broadcasting new position to service ---
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_SEEKBAR);

        initViews();
        setListeners();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



   //Adding Listener to button
     streamSetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            fileStreamAdress = streamSetButton.getText().toString();


            playPauseButtonClicked();
        }
    });

     playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            fileStreamAdress = streamSetButton.getText().toString();


             playPauseButtonClicked();
         }


     });



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return podcastPlayerLayout;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `this` is referring to the Adapter not a Context. Try:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myPlayService.class);
```

or

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myPlayService.class);
// Where MainActivity is the Activity class's name
```

The reason is Activity is a subclass of Context, while Adapters are not...

Answer (score 0):

> Intent is undefined

You will get these errors when variable is not defined in scope (or) type is not clear for compiler.

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_SEEKBAR);
```

In this line you haven't type of the variable `intent`.

It should be something like

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_SEEKBAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

among your imports, and the variable `intent` and `serviceIntent` declared as either class variables or local variables, like:

```
Intent intent, serviceIntent;
```

Also, make sure you're using the correct Context. In your case, `this` probably isn't what you're looking for. Try:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, myPlayService.class); //OR
serviceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myPlayService.class); //OR
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myPlayService.class);
```